# How to zoom a pdf image dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

How to zoom a pdf image (in jsp) dynamically based on textfields.( i.e some portion of the image need to zoom based on the focus into a specific textfield,  and some other portion of image if we have focused into another field..)
i have used iframe to dispaly the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use with pdf.js - https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Here is working example : http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: not mean to that out put...iam just asking about how to zoom a pdf..for example we have a fill form fields using a pdf (at left side of fields) if cursor is focused into firstname field the corresponding area of the pdf will be zoom same for all the fields.....